# Can I change 'rpath' in an already compiled binary?

Tags: linux, linker, elf

I have an old executable that's scheduled for the scrap heap, but it's not there yet. It relies on some libs that have been removed from my environment, but I have some stub libs someplace where it works fine. Id like to point this executable to these stub libs. Yes, i could set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but this executable is called from many scripts, and many users and I'd love to fix it in one spot.

I don't have source for this, and would be hard to get it. I was thinking - can I edit this file, using an ELF aware editor, and add a simple PATH to rpath to have it hit the new libs? Is this possible, or once you create an ELF binary, you fix things to locations and they can't be moved?

Comment: Wrap it into a shellscript that sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH and calls the binary. Put the shell script in a place that is in the callers's PATH.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is inherited by child processes. You might not want that.

Comment: @will yeah that and I already said I don't want to do that. :)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

There is a tool called `chrpath` which can do this - it's probably available in your distribution's packages.

Comment: Just a note for mac users, `install_name_tool` can do this with the `-rpath` flag

Comment: If you get the error: `<binary>: no rpath or runpath tag found.`, you can't use `chrpath` to replace it, but you can use `patchelf` in this case: `patchelf --set-rpath /path/to/libaries <binary>`

Comment: I prefer chrpath if possible since, while it's more universal, patchelf has some long standing bug that dramatically inflates the size of your libraries/executables.

Comment: @taranaki: Which version of patchelf are you talking about?

Comment: _chrpath_ has got a severe limitation: _it can only replace an RPATH with one of equal or shorter length_ (man page of rpath version 0.16)

Comment: @hagello I don't remember, and it may be fixed by now.

Answer (score 232):

There is a more universal tool than `chrpath` called [`patchelf`](http://nixos.org/patchelf.html). It was originally created for use in making packages for Nix and NixOS (packaging system and a GNU/Linux distribution).

In case there is no rpath in a binary (here called rdsamp), `chrpath` fails:

```
chrpath -r '$ORIGIN/../lib64' rdsamp 
rdsamp: no rpath or runpath tag found.
```

On the other hand,

```
patchelf --set-rpath '$ORIGIN/../lib64' rdsamp
```

succeeds just fine.

Comment: Especially, `patchelf` is able to add an rpath to a binary that does not contain an rpath, yet - where `chrpath` only seem to be able to modify an already present entry.

Comment: As a general note, it's worth understanding the subtle distinction between `rpath` and `runpath`.  Basically, one can override `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and the other can't. For details, see http://blog.tremily.us/posts/rpath/

Comment: The annoying thing is that both `chrpath` and `patchelf` are sloppy with their terminology. For example, the `patchelf` command shown above will change `runpath` but not `rpath` unless you also provide the `--force-rpath` option.

Comment: @superbatfish Yes, but the difference usually doesn't matter. This  entry from the CHANGELOG of `patchelf` explains it: "`--set-rpath`, `--shrink-rpath` and `--print-rpath` now prefer
  `DT_RUNPATH` over `DT_RPATH`, which is obsolete.  When updating, if both
  are present, both are updated.  If only DT_RPATH is present, it is
  converted to `DT_RUNPATH` unless `--force-rpath` is specified.  If
  neither is present, a `DT_RUNPATH` is added unless `--force-rpath` is
  specified, in which case a `DT_RPATH` is added." The name of the option was probably kept unchanged for compatibility reasons.

Comment: How do you add more than one?

Comment: @AndrewHundt Path separator on UNIX is a colon. See examples at https://nixos.org/patchelf.html. `patchelf --set-rpath /opt/my-libs/lib:/foo/lib program` This causes the dynamic linker to search in /opt/my-libs/lib and /foo/lib for the shared libraries needed by program.`

Comment: this is so good. i am experimenting with running it on a bunch of .so files and a binary executable. i can go ubuntu -> debian -> fedora with no problem so far.

Comment: By far the best answer, this should be the accepted answer instead!

Comment: What does $ORIGIN mean?

Comment: @bruziuz `$ORIGIN` expands to the directory containing the program or shared object. Expansion happens when you execute the binary, not when you run `patchel`. To prevent shell expansion when running patchelf, the rpath is single quoted. It's explained in man pages. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html

Comment: Recently, I encountered a trap when using `$ORIGIN` and symbolic links to shared libraries: Be aware that `$ORIGIN` denotes the directory of the symbolic link, which is _not_ necessarily the directory containing the program of shared library (yes, I'm talking to you, @user7610). The lesson is: If you want to use symbolic links to shared libraries, try to keep both in the same directory. Else you have to use `patchelf --set-rpath` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. (At least for my version of the dynamic linker.)

Answer (score 48):

Just like @user7610 said, the right way to go is the [`patchelf`](http://nixos.org/patchelf.html) tool.

But, I feel that I can give a more comprehensive answer, covering all the commands one needs to do exactly that.

**For a comprehensive article on the subject, click [here](https://trugman-internals.com/elf-loaders-libraries-executables/)**

First of all, many developers talk about `RPATH`, but they actually mean `RUNPATH`. These are two different optional dynamic sections, and the loader handles them very differently. You can read more about the difference between them in the link I mentioned before.

For now, just remember:

- If `RUNPATH` is set, `RPATH` is ignored
- `RPATH` is deprecated and should be avoided
- `RUNPATH` is preferred because it can be overridden by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

**See the current R[UN]PATH**

```
readelf -d <path-to-elf> | egrep "RPATH|RUNPATH"
```

**Clear the R[UN]PATH**

```
patchelf --remove-rpath <path-to-elf>
```

Notes:

- Removes both `RPATH` and `RUNPATH`

**Add values to R[UN]PATH**

```
patchelf [--force-rpath] --set-rpath "<desired-rpath>" <path-to-elf>
```

Notes:

- `<desired-path>` is a colon separated directories list, e.g: `/my/libs:/my/other/libs`
- If you specify `--force-rpath`, sets `RPATH`, otherwise sets `RUNPATH`

Comment: `-Wl,-R,<desired-rpath> -Wl,--enable-new-dtags` sets `DT_RUNPATH`, and that is the one most folks should use. `RUNPATH` can be overridden by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so folks should not use `--force-rpath`.

Comment: @jww I see that I didn't add a comment about the deprecation of RPATH, so I added one just now. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the example `<desired-path>` uses a colon; it should be a comma (that is: `/my/libs,/my/other/libs`).

Comment: @AlanDeSmet, I don't know about the comma, but the colon works for me.

Comment: RPATH might be deprecated, but using RUNPATH can lead to "unexpected" corner cases. See, for example, https://www.qt.io/blog/2011/10/28/rpath-and-runpath .

Comment: "*... **colon** (not **comma**) separated ...*".

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, replacing XORIGIN with $ORIGIN.

`chrpath -r '\$\ORIGIN/../lib64' httpd`