# Android NDK shared libraries

Tags: android, android-ndk, dlopen, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am trying to build a native library for an Android application. I have 2 libraries and I need to link them in my final library, but I have some problems.
The Android.mk code:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS     := -Wall -Wfloat-equal -std=c99

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)/..

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_MODULE            := cpu-lib
  LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/cpu/inc
  LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS   := $(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
  LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS     := -llog
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := $(LOCAL_PATH)/cpu/lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libdemoDSP.so
  LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES  := gnustl_static
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_MODULE            := dsp-lib
  LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/dsp/inc
  LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS   := $(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
  LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS     := -llog
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := $(LOCAL_PATH)/dsp/lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libfn_dsp.so
  LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES  := gnustl_static
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := process
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := process.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := cpu-lib dsp-lib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The problem is that the dlopen won't find the libfn_dsp.so.
The ndk-depends output:

```
ndk-depends libs\arm64-v8a\libprocess.so
WARNING: Could not find library: ./obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfn_dsp.so
libprocess.so
liblog.so
libdemoDSP.so
libstdc++.so
libm.so
libdl.so
libc.so
./obj/local/arm64-v8a/libfn_dsp.so
```

It seems that is something strange with that lib. Does somebody know what might be?

Answer (score 0):

The **libfn_dsp.so** binary was - for whatever reason - built <s>with [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath)</s> without SONAME. You can use **objdump** utility (bundled in Android NDK) to see the proof.

If you cannot rebuild this library, follow the discussion here: *[Can I change 'rpath' in an already compiled binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769141/can-i-change-rpath-in-an-already-compiled-binary)*.

Comment: Unfortunately, the objdump -x and chrpath --list returned me no rpath. I have managed to build the library with soname and solved the problem, but now I have another library and no source code. It also has no rpath and I have the same problem

Comment: Are you sure you use the NDK version of objdump? Note that the *host* binary may show different results. Why does soname save the situation?

Comment: I have never tried this, but maybe the [patchelf](https://www.mankier.com/1/patchelf) utility can let you set SONAME for the prebuilt library, and then it will get loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `libfn_dsp.so miss SONAME info`, you can use "`readelf --dynamic libfn_dsp.so |grep SONAME`" then check output info is empty, And you can use "`readelf --dynamic libdemoDSP.so |grep SONAME`", which output info is "`libdemoDSP.so`".

how to fix:
1. If you have `libfn_dsp.so` source code, you can compile it with newest NDK, or with older NDK add "`-Wl,-soname,libfn_dsp.so`" option.
2. Otherwise, you use `System.loadLibrary("fn_dsp")` manually load `libfn_dsp.so` before loading `libprocess.so`.