# How to remove absolute path in shared library linked by LLVM LD

Tags: macos, ld, rpath

In Mac OS X, when using LLVM LD to link some C code (which will result in a shared library called `libA.so`) that has a dependency to a shared library called `libX.so`, the absolute full path of `libX.so` is included in the list of shared libraries that `libA.so` needs. In other words, when doing `ldd libA.so` the following is shown:

```
(...)
/Users/foo/workspace/libX.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
(...)
```

How can one link the C code so that only the relative path of `libX.so` is included? In other words, when doing `ldd libA.so` the following is shown instead:

```
(...)
./workspace/libX.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
(...)
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769141/can-i-change-rpath-in-an-already-compiled-binary

Comment: @compor the question you're linking is `ELF` linux specific and so is the accepted answer's `chrpath` tool.

Comment: @Kamil.S yes, although [it's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769141/can-i-change-rpath-in-an-already-compiled-binary) the most relevant and the accepted answer has a comment for mac uses mentioning `install_name_tool` with the use of the `-rpath` option. It just takes a bit of extra time to search properly.

Comment: @compor Perhaps adding  `macos` tag to the question would make it more explicit and easily findable. I gotta admit I did initially miss the comment you're referring to.