# Executable is looking for a different shared library version than what is in path

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I received an executable that was compiled on a 64 bit linux machine. I'm currently working with this executable on a 64 bit linux machine.

When executing the code, I keep getting the error

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmpi_usempif08.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`libmpi_usempif08.so.40` is not in my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but the following are

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 blah blah      26 Jun 17  2016 libmpi_usempif08.so -> libmpi_usempif08.so.11.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 blah blah      26 Jun 17  2016 libmpi_usempif08.so.11 -> libmpi_usempif08.so.11.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 blah blah  286931 Jun 17  2016 libmpi_usempif08.so.11.1.0
```

Is there any way I can tell my executable (without recompiling it because I don't have that option) to look for these instead of the one that ends in `.so.40`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change 'rpath' in an already compiled binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13769141/608639). Update the rpath for the location of `libmpi_usempif08.so.40`. Or, make `libmpi_usempif08.so.40` a link to another compatible version of the library.

Comment: @jww Thanks. With the latter (link) method, is that with symlinks? Edit: I don't think this is with symlinks. I thought symlinks is for linking files that exist. In this case the `libmpi_usempif08.so.40` doesn't actually exist.