# Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH after using setcap

Tags: linux, sockets, permissions, network-programming, port

I'm developing a small C++ tool that makes use of [libtins](http://libtins.github.io/). To run its network sniffer with enough permissions, it is required whether to use sudo or `setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep <binaryFile>`.

As my program is being called from the web server, when the user interacts with the frontend, I cannot use sudo, so I opted for the setcap solution. The problem is, [setcap disables LD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux), so the program will complain about not finding a library. How should I set the library path?

I've also seen [mentions to authbind](https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443), but I don't quite understand how can I grant the program access to all ports.

Comment: Can you use `LD_RUN_PATH` or the `ld` option `-rpath` at link time?

Comment: I'm using Meson build system, and if I understood it correctly, [that is not supported](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/2567). At least I didn't find a way to make it work. I guess my options are to link statically or install to system, right?

Comment: Maybe [change rpath in the executable itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769141/can-i-change-rpath-in-an-already-compiled-binary)?