# Can you relink/modify relative shared library look up paths?

Tags: c++, build, linker, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I am running into the following situation. Project A has libraries A1, A2, A3... That follow their own directory structure. For example:

```
Libaries/
|
|--Dir1/
|  |
|  |--A1.so
|  |--A2.so
|
|--Dir2/
|  |--A3.so
|  |--A4.so
```

In this case Project A compiles just fine. The libraries of project A are dependencies for project B and a script (that I have no control over) copies them onto B's directory in a flat hierarchy i.e this

```
BLibraries/
|--A1.so
|--A2.so
|--A3.so
|--A4.so
```

So the relative paths are no longer the same.

B loads symbols from these libraries dynamically through dlopen. In this case, If A1 needs symbols from A2, B they appear as undefined and so B fails to load A1.

Is there a way I can poke the files Ai.so and tell them "Hey that other library whose symbols you need is actually over here now"?

Comment: This looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769141/can-i-change-rpath-in-an-already-compiled-binary  If it works, I'll close the question as a dup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can poke the files Ai.so and tell them "Hey that other library whose symbols you need is actually over here now"?

You can use [patchelf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/patchelf.1.html) to do that, but you *shouldn't*.

Since *you* control how `A*.so` is built, you should set their `RPATH` so that it works "out of the box". Adding `-rpath=/path/to/BLibraries` to `A*.so` link command is probably all that's needed.