# Setuptools not appending runtime path added via extra_link_args parameter to link module to shared library

Tags: python, c++, cmake, setuptools, pybind11

I am building a python wrapper around a C++/CUDA project (called DEM-Engine) with the assistance of pybind11 and setuptools for packaging. My build works successfully and running pip3 install on the PyPi package DEME builds everything successfully from the sdist package.

However, my module DEME relies on a shared library that is built during the build process of the DEME package. To try to link my module to the shared library, I am adding the following to my Extension function definition:

```
conda_prefix = os.environ.get("CONDA_PREFIX")

super().__init__(name, sources=[], extra_link_args=['-Wl,-rpath,' + conda_prefix + '/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lib'], libraries=["libDEMERuntimeDataHelper"], include_dirs=["./src/DEM/", "./src/DEM/VariableTypes"], extra_objects=["./build"])
```

Via this method, I can ensure that the location of the shared library (which is always placed in the lib folder in site-packages) can be found. However, when importing my module I run into the error that the shared library could not be found.

Appending the location `conda_prefix + '/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lib` to my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ensures that everything is found and everything works correctly then.

Could someone please help me understand what I can do to ensure the end user does not have to define the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable every time they install the package?

Comment: You can use a tool described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769141/can-i-change-rpath-in-an-already-compiled-binary or use `-rpath` with the linker.

Comment: I have tried to set runtime_library_dirs as well, however after checking the output of ldd for my module, I can see that the directories aren't searched. I was hoping to come up with a solution that would not require special work for the end user. Is there another way?

Comment: If rpath does not work for you, then you can use `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`.