How to link with a custom dynamic (.so) library with Rust?
I have Rust code which is supposed to link with a dynamic library which is located in /path/to/library/build. I'm making Rust bindings/wrapper for another library written in C.
In build.rs:
println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=-lawesome");

libawesome.so is located in /path/to/library/build.
Using this
RUSTFLAGS="-L /path/to/library/build -C link-args=-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/library/build" cargo test

I can link and execute the tests which use symbols from the dynamic the library while
RUSTFLAGS="-C link-args=-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/library/build" cargo test

Why do I need to use -L here?
How would I do this without using RUSTFLAGS?
I was expecting not to have to use -L.

Because the library is in a non-standard location. How do you expect the linker to know where the library is located?

But why both flags? Why is it not enough to use "-C link-args=-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/library/build" only?

Does this answer your question: What's the difference between -rpath and -L?

TLDR the duplicate: -rpath is so that your program will be able to find the library at runtime. -L is so that the linker will be able to find the library at compile-time. Note that cargo build should work with just the -L. OTOH cargo run will require both (-L when compiling then -rpath when running).

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13769141/5397009
